# Configure Survey Graphical Summary to hide values without a selection

Tags: 2010, survey

I made a survey where there is a long list for a dropdown. When I go view the Graphical Summary, it displays every single survey question option with a 0%. Is there a way to show only the survey question options with a value on it? For example, I have a list of 50 states, but only want to show states which has a vote on it and hides the rest of the states until it has been voted on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. Instead of using the Choice/Dropdown option, I used the Look Up option and pulled the options from a custom list. Now only the choices with values on them show up on the graphical summary page.